# Add a div to caret position in draft-js editor

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am using `draftjs-editor-plugins`. I want to get a functionality like this
[image]

In short looking for something like this http://ichord.github.io/Caret.js/ in React. Or any workaround to integrate it with react?

Comment: Why not just use the library like normal? Is not using jQuery a requirement?

Comment: We don't use jQuery in our codebase so.